# Blur Part of the Image Background Behind a DIV with bgStretcher using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

How can I blur the part of an image behind a specific DIV. I am currently using [bgStretcher](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html) JQuery plugin to stretch a large imaeg across the browser window, so when it is resized the image will stretch to fit.

The plugin creates the following HTML:

```
<div id="bgstretcher" class="bgstretcher" style="width: 1920px; height: 534px;">
    <ul>
        <li class="bgs-current" style="display: list-item;">
            <img src="images/backgrounds/bg-2.jpg" alt="" style="width: 1920px; height: 1280px;">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a div with position absolute that floats on top of the bgstretcher DIV and has content in it. I want the part of the image behind this DIV to be blurred out in some degree so elements within this div sill be more readable.

I want to the blur to get updated and be consistent when I resize the browser window. I tried [Blur.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Blur.js) with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
$('.blur').blurjs({
    source: '.bgstretcher img',
    radius: 7,
    overlay: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
});
```

I want this solution to work with at least IE 8+, Chrome, Safari and Firefox. I'm searching for something that is easy to implement, in form of a plugin. I prefer the option to still use Blur.js but I want to make it work with bgStretcher.

Comment: I think this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17134789/1947286