# Frosted glass effect over HTML text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a blurred opaque overlay to a load of text content.

All the solutions and posts I've come across are for image backgrounds, not just HTML text content.

What I want will very much look like the floating overlays on http://www.blurjs.com/ but instead of a background image, it will be HTML text (`<p>` tags, `<h1>` tags etc).

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a59w04nh/) of roughly what I need, but I want the white opaque background colour of the overlay to be blurred also.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5) blur(10px); ???

Comment: @GibboK this will blur the content of the overlay and not the content behind it as OP seems to want.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to blur the content behind it, just the overlay and the text with the overlay - good point though, forgot to mention I tried that.

Comment: Can you please add a picture of what you want to achieve? is it the box with code or the box with text `attention`?

Comment: or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092299/how-to-use-css-and-javascript-to-create-a-blurred-frosted-background