# Is it possible to apply a blur filter to a background-image of a div with position:fixed, from another div rendered on top of it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

***How is my question different from the proposed duplicate:***

I want *only the part of* the `div.background-pic` (the div with the background image) which is behind `div.lower` (the div with the translucent blue color), to *just appear to be* blurred.

***Explained:***

As you can see, the `div.background-pic` is `position:fixed` (which means it is out of the flow, and does not scroll), while the rest of the page scrolls vertically, which implies that there are different parts of `div.background-pic` behind the `div.lower` at different times (while the page is being scrolled).

So it is obvious that we don't want to do anything to the div with the image itself, but do something (apply some kind of filter if there is one, etc.) on the `div.lower` such that it causes the *part of the* `background-image` of the div which is behind it, to appear blurred.

---

***QUESTION:***

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/0w1vh4gu/)

In the following SSCCE, I want the part of the (`background-image` of) `.background-pic` which is behind `.lower` (and is partially visible because .lower is translucent) to appear blurred out. Is that possible?

```css
.background-pic {
  background-image: url(http://khongthe.com/wallpapers/nature/beautiful-valley-45851.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
.top-blur {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.upper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 127, 80, 0.5);
}
.lower {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.51);
}
```

```html
<div class="background-pic">

  <div class="top-blur">
    <div class="upper"></div>
    <div class="lower"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

*NOTE: CSS only solution is preferred.*

---

Comment: @TinyGiant I added an edit to the top of the question, explaining how my question is different from that question. Can the "This question may already have an answer here:" label be removed if my edit is satisfactory?

Comment: I don't believe it would be possible because you're blurring the overlaying element, even a opacity wouldn't do what you intend. I can't answer, but I believe it's not possible. You may want to edit with photoshop?

Comment: I agree with @BillyPurvis, this is not possible with CSS, I doubt you could even do this with JavaScript. But, you're right, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: However, it does look like this can be done with HTML5's `<canvas>` http://stackoverflow.com/a/17134789/4639281, which offers a new duplicate. If this solves the problem, @ping me and I'll get another user to suggest that as a duplicate (as I've retracted my close vote and can't vote again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way with some `js` to get this result, using `clipping path` and some repositioning on scroll. Like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="background-pic-top"></div>
<div class="background-pic-bottom"></div>
<div class="top-blur" id="scrollingDiv">
    <div class="upper">
        <svg class="clip-svg" width="400" height="500" style="position: relative">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="uppersvg" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="300" />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="lower">
        <svg>
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="lowersvg" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="200">
                    <rect x="0" y="300" width="400" height="200" />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var elem = document.getElementById('scrollingDiv');
    var clipUp = document.getElementById('uppersvg');
    var clipDown = document.getElementById('lowersvg');

    elem.onscroll = function (e) {
        clipDown.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0].setAttribute('y', 300 - elem.scrollTop);
        clipUp.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0].setAttribute('y', 0 - elem.scrollTop);
    }
```

CSS:

```
   body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .background-pic-top {
            background-image:url(http://khongthe.com/wallpapers/nature/beautiful-valley-45851.jpg);
            background-size:cover;
            position:fixed;
            z-index:-1;
            height:400px;
            width:400px;
            clip-path: url(#uppersvg);
            -webkit-clip-path: url(#uppersvg);
        }
        .background-pic-bottom {
            background-image:url(http://khongthe.com/wallpapers/nature/beautiful-valley-45851.jpg);
            background-size:cover;
            position:fixed;
            z-index:-1;
            height:400px;
            width:400px;
            clip-path: url(#lowersvg);
            -webkit-clip-path: url(#lowersvg);
            -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
            filter: blur(5px);
        }
        .top-blur {
            height:400px;
            width:400px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .upper {
            height:300px;
            width:100%;
            background-color: rgba(255, 127, 80, 0.5);
        }
        .lower {
            top: 200px;
            height:200px;
            width:100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.51);
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4f601tt7/7/

Won't be cross-browser but it seems to work on Chrome and Firefox.