# Re-Creating Aero Glass for Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, aero-glass

So, this concept is simple, but the code is complicated...

Here's a partial example - look at the navbar on this site:
[navbar aero glass example](http://chronixaggression.com)
It is just a DIV with a tiled background with maybe a 50% opacity.

Now, to get the full aero glass effect, we need to blur whatever is behind this DIV / navbar. So, in this example, the navbar needs to blur the underlying DIV background image. This is what confuses me.

The closest thing I could find to a blur filter was this:

img {

```
-webkit-filter: blur(5px); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
filter: blur(5px);
```

}

But the above only works for the image element for Firefox and not IE.

Basically, I need a way to create a DIV, and blur whatever is behind that DIV element, and have it work for all browsers.

Thx in advance.

Comment: an "easy way" is coming, maybe, http://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop-filter

Comment: but, IE - you have two chances, buckleys and none - IE is dead dead dead

Comment: Your first post was good, second was confusing.

Comment: IE is old and not developed, so any new CSS (and even old CSS) just does not, and will never, work - having said that, IE may work with `-ms-filter`

Comment: "Buckleys and non" = "no chance." Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could screenshot your page into a canvas. 
Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Then blur the canvas and clip it with a div.
The problem is that you need to refresh the screenshot in order to give the look of a real-time blurry effect (Which is VERY slow and is going to lag most of your visitors).

This could help you: https://github.com/keithwhor/canvasBlurRect

**EDIT**
An answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969917/7090648 (tagged) does what you want.

Comment: Well, assuming the navbar blurs the background in the example you provide - what if the image behind the blurred div element is a responsive image? Will the blur effect still work? I ask because I do not understand your link. I am not comfortable with "...JavaScript, the Canvas API and the DOM API." That's why I am posting. Thx for the feedback.

Comment: Wow, it works in the example! Good job! What search terms did you use to find this answer? Also, I voted you up. It won't show since this was my first post! Damn man, I can't believe you found the answer! I am a happy person now!

Comment: @No-U-Turn "js realtime blur effect" as simple as that :)

Comment: After studying all the links, this is what I need: http://jsfiddle.net/kmxD3/1/ Only this example works with Firefox, and not IE. I will research more tomorrow, need sleep now. Thx again ppl!

Comment: It does work for chrome too. As you can see from http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters, filter does not work for IE