# iOS-like semi-opaque modal which blurs the background behind it

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, render

I'd like to revisit [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759498/mask-that-blurs-content-behind-it) from 2012. I wonder if anything has changed from the time that particular question was posted?

Is it possible to create a modal which doesn't require a `canvas` rendering of the page, which is then displayed and cropped to the desired size?

If so, is there a way to display this cross-browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that @Michael Wasser mentioned "-webkit-filter" in a previous question. That's how you would do it these days without relying on Javascript.

```
img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

See [this HTML5Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/) for more on this.

How supported is it?

caniuse.com says that global support is at [43.67% at the moment](http://caniuse.com/css-filters). All the recent Chrome, WebKit (Safari), and Opera (now that it switched to Blink) should have them. Not sure what the plans are for Mozilla and Microsoft.

In Firefox, you can probably use [SVG filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Example.3A_Filtering) to recreate the blur.